# Multi developer environment python and sqlalchemy

Tags: python, database, development-environment

I'm currently exploring using python to develop my server-side implementation. I've decided to use SQLAlchemy for database stuff.

What I'm not currently to sure about is how it should be set up so that more than one developer can work on the project. For the code it is not a problem but how do I handle the database modifications? How do the users sync databases and how should potential data be set up? Should/can each developer use their own sqlite db for development?

For production postgresql will be used but the developers must be able to work offline.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Alembic](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/alembic/0.4.2) to manage your DB structure. Keep your migrations under version control in order to ensure that it's easy for developers to keep in sync with changes.
As regards data itself, you can either work with a set of fixtures, or you could write some Fabric commands to import/export Postgres dumps, which you could also keep under version control if necessary – depending on data size, you may not want to keep a large uncompressed SQL dump under version control (though it will compress well using git or hg), however. This aspect of your question depends on the size of your development team, and the size of your database.

Comment: Thanks and for anyone reading I found this: https://github.com/kvesteri/sqlalchemy-fixtures

Comment: on top of the above -- you should consider adding checks in your backend startup code that require certain db migrations to be present.    i've had too many people complain about things breaking, because they didn't realize there was a sql migration they forgot to run.

Comment: thanks. i was thinking of something like a version string in the db and a corresponding in the code somewhere. good to match that on start.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have a python programs or programs to fill databases with test data from scratch. It allows each developer to work from different starting points, but also test with the same environment.